# Unrecognized selector called on Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, appdelegate

I've got a fully working Flutter platform plugin with a demo Flutter app. Flutter app is happily talking to the native code through channels and getting responses. Now I need the app to work in background as well. Following various guides around I found that I need to call `setPluginRegistrantCallback` on my plugin. But if I do that, the app crashes with:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[MyPlugin setPluginRegistrantCallback:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104ed5668'

My code:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    MyPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback({ registry in
        if (!registry.hasPlugin("MyPlugin")) {
            MyPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "MyPlugin"))
        }

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    })
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Any ideas what am I missing? Otherwise the plugin and the Runner app works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your `setPluginRegistrantCallback` method isn't defined in a class called `SwiftMyPlugin`?

Comment: Yes, I get `Type 'SwiftMyPlugin' has no member 'setPluginRegistrantCallback'` when I try to call it on `SwiftMyPlugin`

Comment: Where did you actually define the method then? Is your swift class just called MyPlugin?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as an answer since the OP didn't follow up on my comment.

When you create a Flutter plugin "MyPlugin" using `flutter create --template=plugin my_plugin`, with the [default] iOS language as Swift, two classes are created: `MyPlugin` and `SwiftMyPlugin`. You will most likely be implemented your plugin in `SwiftMyPlugin`. The `MyPlugin` class, however, extends `NSObject<FlutterPlugin>`, which does contain a `setPluginRegistrantCallback` method, therefore calling `MyPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback` is NOT a compile error, but you almost certainly want to call `SwiftMyPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback`.

Comment: I get `Type 'SwiftMyPlugin' has no member 'setPluginRegistrantCallback'`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Tom?

Comment: This has been a while ago but if I remember correctly it didn't work for me so I had to use different approach.